# How to display an alert box containing Html tags?

Tags: jsp, alert

I want display the string containing HTML tags in an alert box . the onclick event triggers this action but the alert is not being displayed..

This is the javascript function for displaying the alert box..

```
function DisplayNext(Next){
            alert(Next);

        }
```

The Jsp is

```
String test="DisplayNext(\"<table><table cellspacing='10' cellpadding='10'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Lattitude </th><th>Longitude</th><th>Gpsid</th><th>Speed</th><th>Type</th><th>Routeid</th><th>Status</th><th>Passengers</th><th>Capacity</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>20.0</td><td>51.0</td><td>19.0</td><td>30.0</td><td>Bus</td><td>3</td><td>Active</td><td>20</td><td>65</td><td><a href=Deletetable.jsp?command=deleteVehicles&vehicle_ID=1><img  src='Delete.gif' alt='Delete' title='Delete' width='20' height='20'></a></td><td><a href=Home.jsp?command%3Dvehicle%26commandid%3Dupdate_form%26Vehicle_ID%3D1%26vehicle_locX%3D20.0%26vehicle_locY%3D51.0%26vehicle_Gpsid%3D19.0%26vehicle_speed%3D30.0%26vehicle_type%3DBus%26vehicle_routeid%3D3%26vehicle_status%3DActive%26vehicle_passengerno%3D20%26vehicle_capacity%3D65%26vehicle_agentid%3D3 ><img src='Update.gif' alt='Update' title='Update' width='20' height='20'></a></td></tr><table cellspacing='10' cellpadding='10'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Lattitude </th><th>Longitude</th><th>Gpsid</th><th>Speed</th><th>Type</th><th>Routeid</th><th>Status</th><th>Passengers</th><th>Capacity</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>20.0</td><td>51.0</td><td>19.0</td><td>30.0</td><td>Bus</td><td>3</td><td>Active</td><td>20</td><td>65</td><td><a href=Deletetable.jsp?command=deleteVehicles&vehicle_ID=1><img  src='Delete.gif' alt='Delete' title='Delete' width='20' height='20'></a></td><td><a href=Home.jsp?command%3Dvehicle%26commandid%3Dupdate_form%26Vehicle_ID%3D1%26vehicle_locX%3D20.0%26vehicle_locY%3D51.0%26vehicle_Gpsid%3D19.0%26vehicle_speed%3D30.0%26vehicle_type%3DBus%26vehicle_routeid%3D3%26vehicle_status%3DActive%26vehicle_passengerno%3D20%26vehicle_capacity%3D65%26vehicle_agentid%3D3 ><img src='Update.gif' alt='Update' title='Update' width='20' height='20'></a></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>-20.134946</td><td>57.527719</td><td>20.0</td><td>50.0</td><td>Bus</td><td>1</td><td>Active</td><td>45</td><td>65</td><td><a href=Deletetable.jsp?command=deleteVehicles&vehicle_ID=2><img  src='Delete.gif' alt='Delete' title='Delete' width='20' height='20'></a></td><td><a href=Home.jsp?command%3Dvehicle%26commandid%3Dupdate_form%26Vehicle_ID%3D2%26vehicle_locX%3D-20.134946%26vehicle_locY%3D57.527719%26vehicle_Gpsid%3D20.0%26vehicle_speed%3D50.0%26vehicle_type%3DBus%26vehicle_routeid%3D1%26vehicle_status%3DActive%26vehicle_passengerno%3D45%26vehicle_capacity%3D65%26vehicle_agentid%3D1 ><img src='Update.gif' alt='Update' title='Update' width='20' height='20'></a></td></tr></table>\")";

                                            NextLink = "<br><a href='#' onclick="+test+"> Next</a>";
```

When the next link is pressed,no alert box is displayed.How do I display it?

I change my codes to something simpler still I am not able to display the html tags using alert box. The codes are in the comment of TheStijn

Comment: I've edited your question to make the JS and JSP show up as code blocks, but they're still unreadable due to the massive line length and weird indenting. You'll get more people helping you if you make an effort to make the question easier to read.

Comment: I assume you're using `alert()` here for debugging purposes? You may find that the browser console gives an easier debugging environment -- if you're using Firefox, install the Firebug extension and try replacing `alert()` with `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using double quotes both in your test string and you href tag. Do this instead:

```
String test = "DisplayNext('ID...')";
```

Comment: I changed my codes to something simpler . String test = "DisplayNext(\"<p align='center'>vimal</p>\")";String NextLink = "<br><a href='#' onclick='"+test+"'> Next</a>";